# General purpose pads of a controller

Tags: memory, configuration, io, microcontroller

What does pad mean?
e.g: I have a statement here
     The module provides dedicated general-purpose pads that can be configured as either inputs or outputs.
So i'm not getting what exactly **pad** here means.
and what is the significance of the **pad**.Why we need the pads when we can directly configure the I/O ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing two concepts here. The ports are on chip. They are configured as inputs or outputs. There is probably a flip flop driving this port. Now there needs to be a way to connect this port to the outside world. There are thin bonding wires (in case of non flip chip designs) that go from the chip to a metal pad. This pad then makes electrical contact to the outer world. So ports -> pads on chip package -> pcb -> outside world. Configuring a pad and configuring a port is the same thing.